External display randomly flickers in black
I bought a brand new Samsung M5 monitor and I would like some help to troubleshoot this issue before I have to disassambly my whole setup to visit the tech support.
The thing is that the external monitor randomly goes black for a second and then recovers. It can flash twice in a short period, a few seconds later flashes once or twice again, and so on. There is no noticeable pattern.
So I'm using 24.04 in a Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5 with Intel Graphics RPL-P. I could tell it shouldn't be a hardware problem because 1) I used to have another monitor and had no issues, 2) I already tested a couple of different cables with no changes in the behavior, and 3) it also works perfectly well in Windows (dual boot).
Here are some command outputs I've found so far in my useless research.
$ LANG=C inxi -Fxxxrzc0 --usb
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-38-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
    clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: gnome-shell
    tools: gsd-screensaver-proxy dm: GDM3 v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    (Noble Numbat)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P [UHD Graphics] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-13 ports: active: HDMI-A-1,eDP-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:a7a8 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Bison Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-5:5 chip-ID: 5986:215f class-ID: fe01
    serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x2280 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x603mm (20.00x23.74")
    s-diag: 788mm (31.04")
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 mapped: HDMI-1 pos: top model: Samsung Smart M50C
    serial: <filter> res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 70
    size: 698x392mm (27.48x15.43") diag: 690mm (27.2") modes: max: 1920x1080
    min: 640x480
  Monitor-2: eDP-1 pos: primary,bottom model: BOE Display 0x0b76
    res: 1920x1200 hz: 60 dpi: 141 size: 345x215mm (13.58x8.46")
    diag: 407mm (16") modes: 1920x1200
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: iris x11: drv: iris
    inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (RPL-P)
    device-ID: 8086:a7a8
(...)


$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2280, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 215mm
   1920x1200     60.00*+  60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   (...)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   (...)


$ sudo lshw -class display
*-display                 
   descripción: VGA compatible controller
   producto: Raptor Lake-P [UHD Graphics]
   fabricante: Intel Corporation
   id físico: 2
   información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
   versión: 04
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuración: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
   recursos: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:177 memoria:6000000000-6000ffffff memoria:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff memoria:4010000000-4016ffffff memoria:4020000000-40ffffffff


$ sudo dmesg -l err
(...)
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Unclaimed access detected prior to suspending
(...)

